# Is there a way to compare items within relative positions in list without using recursions?

Tags: java, list, compare

For example, say I have `[7, 11, 0, 2]`, I want to compare 7 and 2, then 11 and 0.

Two ways I have done this so far by entering the positions in statements like this:
`list[0] > list[list.length-1]` then `list[1] > list[list.length-2]`, I obviously don't want to have to type all this manually as my lists get larger.    Another way I tried to test how to do this was with a recursion but because my program is already running in a recursion I found it a bit confusing..so is it possible to dynamically compare items against each other without the use of a recursion?

The list size is always even and fixed for the life of the program. Any ideas?

note: If I get the idea I can implement it myself but specifically what I'm doing is comparing if each relative item is larger than the other and if they are equal then I compare the next item. For example, [1,5,3,1,5,1], I would compare 1 & 1 and since they are the same I would move to compare 5 & 5 and since they are the same I'd compare 3 & 1. Not sure if there's a non-recusive way to do it, but thought I'd try.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: In the question I mention two approaches and why they don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<list.length/2;i++){
    if(list[i]>list[list.length-1-i]){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

I had to do something similar when checking for palindromes in strings

Comment: Lol sorry :( Hate it when that happens

Comment: ahhh for loop...I'm so dumb for missing that..sorry. Thanks so much..I'm only going further down the list if the previous items are the same but I think I can put an statement to break if they are not similar.  Thanks so much..

Comment: You were on the right track, with the -1, -2 thing. It's good that you understand it :)